# Nextcord creating threads on command

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Is it possible to create a thread on command with nextcord? I tried to do that , but it didn't work. PyCharm did not give me any error message.
Here is my Code:

```
@bot.command(name='create_thread')
@commands.has_permissions(create_public_threads=True)
async def thread(ctx, *, arg):
    await nextcord.create_thread(name=f'{arg}', message=None, auto_archive_duration=60, type=None, reason=None)
```

The error is in `await nextcord.create_thread(name=f'{arg}', message=None, auto_archive_duration=60, type=None, reason=None)`, but I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting, specifically?

Comment: I'm not getting any error.

Comment: It's probably to do with the fact that you are using `nextcord.create_thread` instead of `ctx.create_thread`. Think about it. With the statement you have now, how would discord know _where_ you want to create the thread?

Comment: Didn't work and  I'm not getting an error

Comment: Sorry about that, `ctx.channel.create_thread` should do the trick.

Comment: Ok, but do I need all the parameters I passed?

Comment: Yes, and you would need to await it. Note that if your server is not boosted to level 2, you cannot pass `type=None`. Instead, you should pass `type=nextcord.ChannelType.public_thread`

Comment: Thanks so much! I was really struggling with that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're not specifying the channel to create your thread in. Try the following:

```
@bot.command(name='create_thread')
@commands.has_permissions(create_public_threads=True)
async def thread(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.channel.create_thread(name=f'{arg}', message=None, auto_archive_duration=60, type=None, reason=None)
```

What I did here is remove nextcord, and replace it with ctx.channel. This way, you're specifying the channel to create the thread in. Also the quotes are unnecessary. You can just remove the f'{}' and keep arg.

In my opinion, you shouldn't be using regular commands and should switch to Slash Commands if you're using Nextcord. In this scenario, here's what the command would look like using Slash Commands:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="thread", description="Create a thread in the channel this command is run in", guild_ids=[serverID])
@commands.has_permissions(create_public_threads=True)
async def thread(interaction: nextcord.Interaction, arg: str):
     await interaction.channel.create_thread(name=f'{arg}', message=None, auto_archive_duration=60, type=None, reason=None)
```

You should just be able to copy and paste this code into your Python file. Hope all of this helped **ツ**

Comment: Why slash commands instead of regular ones? what are the benefits?

Comment: Well, there is a visual menu that appears when typing / for better help. Furthermore you get a cool badge. Also it’s easier for the user. Why should I use ? And ! or . for every individual bot. / is organized, built-in, and easy for you and the user